# HtmlWidget source?

Tags: orchardcms

I added a HtmlWidget and it displays fine on the webpage.

I would like to know where the source code is for HtmlWidget. I would like to step through the code when I create a new HtmlWidget, when I save a HtmlWidget, when a HtmlWidget is rendered, etc. Can someone point me where to look.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a ConentType which has a BodyPart, CommonPart, IdentityPart and a WidgetPart, you can see where it's created here: http://orchard.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Orchard.Web/Modules/Orchard.Widgets/Migrations.cs